# Nonlinear differential equation numerical solution+plot

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I have never solved numerically differential equations, but in an optimal control problem I got this one that I cannot solve:

$$
1-f’(x)^2+f’(x)(x +1)+f’’(x)-f’’(x)f’(x)-f’’(x)f’(x)^2=f(x)
$$

I do not have specific initial conditions, but I guess I have to see which ones work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If not addressed by the end of the day i will write an answer detailing the varried boundary condition you describe. Ive asked a variety of questions similar on this topic which you can find in my history in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote in the comment below the kind of conditions I have. My main problem is that one boundary condition is evaluated at a point which is determined by the value of a derivative in that point. So, being completely new to numerical ODE I don't know how to write it down in a code. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hi! If you are still interested in this question here's the updated version: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266051/nonlinear-differential-equations-follow-up-question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 Module[{eqns},
  eqns = {1 - f'[x]^2 + f'[x] (x + 1) + f''[x] - f''[x] f'[x] - 
       f''[x] f'[x]^2 == f[x], f[0] == f0, f'[0] == fp0} // 
    FullSimplify;
  sol = NDSolve[eqns, f, {x, 0, xmax}][[1]];
  Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], f'[x], f''[x]} /. sol],
   {x, 0, xmax},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 14], None},
   PlotLabel -> eqns[[1]],
   PlotLegends -> {"f(x)", "f'(x)", "f''(x)"}]],
 {{f0, 0.75}, -0.99, 0.99, 0.01,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{fp0, 0.25}, -0.99, 0.99, 0.01,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{xmax, 5}, 1, 10, 1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The conditions I should use are maybe weird, but here they are: $$f(0)=0,\ f'(z)=-1$$ where $z$ is the first point at which $f''(z)=0$$ I hope what I wrote makes some sense. Thank you again for your precious help!!

Comment: Hi! If you are still interested in this question here's the updated version: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266051/nonlinear-differential-equations-follow-up-question

Answer (score 6):

*I do not have specific initial conditions, but I guess I have to see which ones work.*

> The advice in situations like this one is to give some information and description of the background material.

**The following is just to get you started**

---

### **Basic commands to look up in the documentation: [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) and [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html).**

---

### **Testing some basic stuff using physics intuition**

---

We assume that the solution has to be normalizable and finite. In other words, in the beginning it should start at `1` and at the end it should go to `0`. I am also assuming that the beginning is `0` and the end is `10`.

---

**Set up the differential equation and initial conditions for specific values**

---

```
eqn = 1 - f'[x]^2 + f'[x] (x + 1) + f''[x] - f''[x] f'[x] - 
    f''[x] f'[x]^2 - f[x] == 0;
intcondtn = {f[0] == 1, f[10] == 0};
```

Now we solve

```
sltnde = NDSolveValue[{eqn, intcondtn}, f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

and we plot to have a look

```
Plot[sltnde, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: plot1]

---

**Free parameters and numerical solutions**

---

```
eqn = 1 - f'[x]^2 + f'[x] (x + 1) + f''[x] - f''[x] f'[x] - 
    f''[x] f'[x]^2 - f[x] == 0;
intcondtn = {f[0] == xx1, f[10] == xx2};
```

and then in order to solve

```
paramsltn = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqn, intcondtn}, 
  f[x], {x, 0, 10}, {xx1, xx2}]
```

and we can plot one of them to have a look

```
Plot[paramsltn[1, 1], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: plot2]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The conditions I should use are maybe weird, but here they are: $$f(0)=0,\ f'(z)=-1$$ where $z$ is the first point at which $f''(z)=0$$ I hope what I wrote makes some sense. Thank you again for your precious help!!

Comment: @Giuliosky what you say makes sense, but I think that you should post another question, link this one and describe this set of conditions explicitly :-)

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice! I will write a new question then!

Comment: @Giuliosky just remember to link this one, i.e this question is a follow-up to and include link and be specific about the conditions you want to impose.

Comment: Hi! If you are still interested in this question here's the updated version: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266051/nonlinear-differential-equations-follow-up-question