# Nonlinear differential equations - follow- up question

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, nonlinear, parametric-functions

I have never solved numerically differential equations and in an optimal control problem I got this one that I cannot solve: $$1-f’(x)^2+f’(x)(x +1)+f’’(x)-f’’(x)f’(x)-f’’(x)f’(x)^2=f(x)$$
The initial conditions I have are the following:
$$f(0)=0, f′(z)=−1$$ where $z$ is the first point at which $f′′(z)=0$ I hope what I wrote makes some sense. Thank you in advance for your help. This is a follow-up to sloppier version of this question I already posed: [Nonlinear differential equation numerical solution+plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265953/nonlinear-differential-equation-numerical-solutionplot)

Comment: You can't really solve this. How would you find the "first" point $z$ where $f''(x)$ is zero in order to use it for initial conditions on $f'(z)$? You'd need to know $f(z)$ first, but that needs to know $z$ first. But that is what you are solving for?

Comment: @Nasser I think that I am the reason that caused this confusion, because I wrote too quickly in the other post. Apologies for the mess and inconvenience to all. Just some comments: if you do `asmpt=AsymptoticDSolveValue[{eqn}, f[x], {x, 0, 3}] // FullSimplify` you get an answer. You can impose on that solution that for `x=0` the answer goes to `0`  and this is setting one of the constants of integration to zero. Then you can examine something like `Solve[(D[asmpt, {x, 2}] /. C[1] -> 0) == 0] // Factor // 
  FullSimplify // Apart` to get three solutions. And then you can start experimenting.

Comment: It's not very elegant and it is only at the level of the asymptotic expansion, but it might give some intuition for the full problem.

Comment: It can't be solved by just brute-force trying a range of $f'(0)=k$ and checking the first time $f'(z)=-1$?

Comment: @Nasser Yes, that's why I was confused indeed by the problem I got. It seems a circular argument.

Comment: @josh yes, I think that brute force method would work. I will try to implement it using Mathematica!

Comment: @Giuliosky:  Thanks,  I'd like to see your results.  Just generate a table of functions $f(x)$ from NDSolve say from $-100\leq x\leq 100$  for various values of $-10\leq k\leq 10$  with $\Delta k=0.1$ or so.  Then analyze each for values of $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ in that interval.  Search for $f'(x)$ close to 1 then check what $f''(x)$ is at that value.  Or maybe $1000$.   If there isn't one then maybe challenge should be "how close can we get to your requirements?"

Comment: @josh Thanks to you! I will try and if I manage to do this I will post my solution. Unfortunately, it's the very first time I use Mathematica therefore it will take me a bit of time to understand how to do it.

Comment: @Giuliosky:  Ok,  I'll try to set it up sometime today or tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There appears to be no solution for the ODE system in the question.  To begin, obtain an explicit expression for `f''[x]`.

```
First@SolveValues[eq, f''[x]]
(* (1 - f[x] + f'[x] + x*f'[x] - f'[x]^2)/(-1 + f'[x] + f'[x]^2) *)
```

where `eq` is the ODE in the question.  The ODE therefore becomes singular for values `f'[x]`

```
SolveValues[Denominator[%] == 0, f'[x]]
(* {1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])} *)
```

Next, plot `f'[x]` for a range of `f'[0]` values, and superimpose on the plot the singular values just determined, as well as the desired `f'[x] = -1`.

```
funp = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == y}, f'[x], {x, 0, 10}, {y}]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[funp[y], {y, -3, 2, .2}], {x, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> {-4, 4}]
Plot[{-1, 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])}, {x, 0, 6}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed]]
Show[%, %%]
```

[image]

Visibly, where `f'[x] = -1`, `f''[x]` is nowhere near zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @bbgodfrey:  Supurb!  Thank you.